# Newton's laws for an object thrown radially upward from the surface of the earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

The acceleration due to gravity on an object thrown radially upward with a height x(t) from the surface of the earth is given as $a(t) = -\dfrac{gR^2}{(x+R)^2}$, where R is the radius of the Earth. I am having trouble deriving this. Can anyone help please ? thank you.

Comment: Do you know about Newton's expression for gravitational force? Look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from user256872,

$$\dfrac{GMm}{R^2}\quad \Longleftrightarrow\quad g=\dfrac{GM}{R^2}$$

so you can write

$$gR^2 =  GM$$ and since $$F_g=\dfrac{GMm}{r^2}$$ then

$$F = \frac{gR^2m}{r^2}=ma$$and so $$a= -\frac{gR^2}{r^2}$$you know that $r=(x+R)^2$. Note the negtive sign signifies direction.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: that's ok. hope u do well in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

At the surface of the earth (distance $R$ from the center), $$F_g=mg=\dfrac{GMm}{R^2}\quad \Longleftrightarrow\quad g=\dfrac{GM}{R^2}$$

And at some height $r=x+R$, you know that $F_g=\dfrac{GMm}{r^2}$.